# Funnels computation via SOS optimization: failing verification of rho

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, drake

I have implemented an optimization problem via SOS optimization that output the rho value for a time-varying RoA estimation. It consists in a bilinear alternation of two optimization problems and I am applying it to the dynamics of a torque-limited simple pendulum. The nominal trajectory has been found via Direct Collocation and the control policy comes from a time-varying LQR controller.

My implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/FedericoGirlanda/SOS-bilinear-alternation) and can be easily run locally. This code include a verification script and the results can be found in the file "results.pdf". My question regards this, why I am obtaining simulations that fails to achieve the goal region even if I am starting in the estimated RoA? I am not expecting this behaviour from an inner estimation such has the one that I have implemented. Are there other possible reasons for such a result?

Answer (score 0):

> My question regards this, why I am obtaining simulations that fails to achieve the goal region even if I am starting in the estimated RoA? I am not expecting this behaviour from an inner estimation such has the one that I have implemented. Are there other possible reasons for such a result

I haven't run your code. From a quick glance of your implementation. When doing the SOS verification, you used taylor expansion to get the polynomial trajectory. On the other hand, the simulation uses the original dynamics (with sin functions). Hence the verification dynamics and the original dynamics can be quite different.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have now take into account this modification in my code. 
However, it seems that the failing simulations still happen. I was expecting this since also with another RoA estimation method (that did not use the approximation) I was obtaining this behaviour.
Can it be something else in your opinion? thank you very much for the attention.

Comment: I have added this modifications in the repo. Furthermore, I have included the result of the other method that I have implemented for this system. In my opinion, this gives a good point of view about the "simulation RoA". It is very narrow, can it depends on some integration errors in the simulation? I am using a 4th order "runge kutta" integrator.

Comment: One way to check if there is "integration errors" is to compute Vdot along the trajectory. If at each state on that trajectory the Vdot is negative, while V increases from one time step to the next time step, then I think that suggests two possible reasons
1. Either the dynamics in the verification doesn't match with the dynamics in simulation, for example one uses Taylor expanded dynamics, one uses the original dynamics, or the state are in the different coordinates.
2. The integrator has an integration error.

Comment: Thanks again for the advices. I discovered that my dynamics was not shifted in the right way. Now I am obtaining a meaningful Funnel, also comparing it with the one that I have obtained with another estimation method. The problem now is that my Funnel is very narrow as long as I go away for the goal region. In your opinion, how can I improve my estimation? Should I use another Lyapunov function?